# Permanently append a division to an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, jsplumb, interact.js

I am trying to append a division(which resembles an anchor) to an element that I drop from the toolbox when double clicked on. I have been using jsPlumb to achieve the drag and drop functionalities for all the elements except for this particular element in context as I need to resize it as well. I could have used the jsPlumb's resize but for some other reason it didn't work and I resolved to interact.js and the resize and draggable functions of interact.js work perfectly. But, my **issue** is that I need anchors/ tiny divs to be appended to this element as soon as the element is dropped. I've tried the following to make the tiny square division appear on double click, but it keep on affecting all the partition elements in the container and not just the clicked one and this division also disappears when the element is resized. But I need it to be permanently appended to the clicked element.

**interact.js**

```
interact('.partitiondrop').on('dblclick',function () {
    alert(" double clicked");
    var element =  event.target.id;
    var prop = $('<div class="connection" style="background-color: #00AA00 ; width: 30px; height: 30px;">').attr('id', (i+('-prop')));
    $('.partitiondrop').append(prop);
});

interact('.partitiondrop')
    .resizable({
        preserveAspectRatio: true,
        edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true }
    })
    .on('resizemove', function (event) {

        var target = event.target,
            x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
            y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

        // update the element's style
        target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
        target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

        // translate when resizing from top or left edges
        x += event.deltaRect.left;
        y += event.deltaRect.top;

        target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
            'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

        target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
        target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '×' + Math.round(event.rect.height);
    });
```

I tried appending the division to the selected(double clicked) partitiondrop only, by trying to get the ID of the element that was clicked-> variable element. But this didn't work as intended

In the context of the following

```
var prop = $('<div class="connection" style="background-color: #00AA00 ; width: 30px; height: 30px;">').attr('id', (i+('-prop')));
```

*`i`* is a global variable that keeps on incrementing and is used to assign unique IDs to the dropped element.

Comment: There are some weird points in this code. where is the **i** variable coming from  and what's the purpose of the variable **element**  in your first "on" method to listening dbclick event?

Comment: I tried appending the division to the selected(double clicked) partitiondrop only, by trying to get the ID of the element that was clicked-> variable element. But this didn't work as internded

Comment: The i variable was just meant as a count to assign unique ids. This keeps on incrementing with each element drop. So to keep track of the element to which a certain div is appended to, I've assigned the div with the same id(var i) as the clicked element  and an additional "-prop"  keyword

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you use **class** ".partitiondrop" for other elements , if you wanna append on **this particular element** , maybe you can try **$(this)** instead of class **.partitiondrop** that maybe using with other elements , by the way  it's better to provide codepen or jsfiddle on this issue

```
interact('.partitiondrop').on('dblclick',function () {
    alert(" double clicked");
    var element =  event.target.id;
    var prop = $('<div class="connection" style="background-color: #00AA00 ;width: 30px; height: 30px;">').attr('id', (i+('-prop')));
    $(this).append(prop);
});
```

Comment: I already tried using _`this`_  keyword but got this error http://imgur.com/CTaJmFg

Comment: sorry about my tedious question , but these “on” methods is certainly added after dom  rendered completely ? , I mean in **$( document ).ready()** ?

Comment: Yes, they are  `var newAgent = $('<div>').attr('id', i).addClass('partitiondrop');
                    newAgent.css({
                        'top': e.pageY,
                        'left': e.pageX
                    });
                    $('#container').append(newAgent);
                    i++;
                    finalElementCount=i;` This is how I dropped the element within the jsPlumb ready function in the beginning, if it affects the code in anyway.

Comment: ok,sorry about my helpless answer, I had have a look on this plugin's docs ,It seems like it is not working with jquery method within 'on' scope, last suggestion, revise your code to **var element = event.target;element[0].innerHTML +='<div class="connection" style="background-color: #00AA00 ; width: 30px; height: 30px;">';element.setAttribute('id', i + '-prop')**

Comment: Really appreciate your help, but now it produces this error http://imgur.com/RD4TuVT

Comment: how about remove the '[0]' of 'element[0]'

Comment: It does append the division to the partitiondrop but, once I resize the partitiondrop, it disappears hence I guess that the division is not permanently attached to it

Comment: I guess this plugin caches virtual dom after registering 'resizable' event on every elements with specific class , so when the event happen ,it refreshes the page with this virtual dom to render the resized elements , so your new element was abandoned , maybe you can have a try like :

Comment: `interact('.partitiondrop').on('dblclick',function () {
   var element = event.target;
element.innerHTML +='<div  class="connection" style="background-color: #00AA00 ; width: 30px; height: 30px;">';
element.setAttribute('id', i + '-prop');
interact('.partitiondrop').resizable({ ...});
});`
Put the event registering in the callback of dbclick ,but this just test how it works , there should be the proper way to found out.

Comment: It still continues to replace the original element ad add a new one when resized. I think maybe cause I'm using 2 scripts(jsPlumb & interact.js) together, this problem keeps recurring. I there a way in which I can resize the dropped element and still append stuff to it without having to use interact.js?